# Custom confirm dialog style

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular-mdl

I have been trying to use the confirm dialog with a custom size but I haven't found a way to do it.

Is there any way or could it be implemented easily?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/basic - click on the contacts Button

Comment: Maybe something like this?  https://dev.to/costlydeveloper/ngx-confirm-box-for-angular-3cgi